# Is this sentence correct: "Have you found him?"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, verbs, differences

- "Have you found him?"

Referring to a missing person (known to be male), is this correct?

Comment: What do you think it wrong?

Comment: 'Him' needs a referent, though this can be hidden somewhere in earlier dialogue. By mounted courier: "Sheriff, can you come over to the gaol right away? One of our prisoners, Robin Greenwood, a dangerous man, has escaped. All our guards are scouring the nearby woods." ... [3 hours later] Sheriff: "Have you found him?"